# Create unique string of first and last name in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I can do this programmatically, but was looking for a cleaner solution.

Let's say I have the following table:

```
First Name      Last Name
Smith           Albert       
Smith           Alphonse    
Smith           Jason         
Johnson         Charles
Roberts         Chris
Roberts         Christian
```

I want to a create a unique with the following rules

- If the last name is already unique just return just last name
- If same last name return first initial (or more) followed by a period then last name

For Albert Smith I would return **Alb.Smith**
For Charles Johnson I would return **Johnson**
For Christion Roberts  I would return **Christ.Roberts**

Does anyone have any thoughts on how to accomplish this directly in an Oracle SQL statement or should I stick to doing it in a program?

Comment: Interesting, but I am curious how would you do it programmatic. If programmatic is possible, SQL is also possible. For instance, what if there are two "Robert Haddock" and a "Rob Haddock" and by default you trim the last 3 letters, or how would the system make a nick name ?

Comment: If two with the same name then I guess I would just return Robert Haddock without the period.  If I wanted Rob Haddock it would just return Rob Haddock since that is his full name.  So yeah, I guess I need more rules... programatically, it currently re-queries the table adding one letter to the first name until it gets only return.  Trying to avoid the multiple sql calls.

Comment: I get your programmatical approach, Could you please add some more sample data and expected output. That would get you better solutions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Version with [recursive subquery refactoring](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF55268) (CTE), which requires 11gR2:

```
with t (last_name, first_name, orig_rn, part, part_length, remaining) as (
  select last_name, first_name,
    row_number() over (order by last_name, first_name),
    cast (null as varchar2(20)), 0, length(first_name)
  from t42
  union all
  select last_name, first_name, orig_rn,
    part || substr(first_name, part_length + 1, 1),
    part_length + 1,
    remaining - 1
  from t
  where remaining > 0
),
u as (
  select last_name, first_name, orig_rn, part, part_length,
    count(distinct orig_rn) over (partition by last_name) as last_name_count,
    count(distinct orig_rn) over (partition by last_name, part) as part_count
  from t
),
v as (
  select last_name, first_name, orig_rn, part, last_name_count,
  row_number() over (partition by orig_rn order by part_length) as rn
  from u
  where (part_count = 1 or part = first_name)
)
select case when last_name_count = 1 then null
  when part = first_name then first_name || ' '
  else part || '. '
  end || last_name as condendsed_name
from v
where rn = 1
order by orig_rn;
```

Which gives:

```
CONDENSED_NAME                               
----------------------------------------------
Johnson                                        
Chris Roberts                                  
Christ. Roberts                                
Alb. Smith                                     
Alp. Smith                                     
J. Smith
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f6cde/1).

The `t` CTE is recursive. It starts with the original table rows and generates additional rows for each possible contraction of the first name:

```
with t (last_name, first_name, orig_rn, part, part_length, remaining) as (
  select last_name, first_name,
    row_number () over (order by last_name, first_name),
    cast (null as varchar2(20)), 0, length(first_name)
  from t42
  union all
  select last_name, first_name, orig_rn,
    part || substr(first_name, part_length + 1, 1),
    part_length + 1,
    remaining - 1
  from t
  where remaining > 0
)
select last_name, first_name, part
from t
where last_name = 'Johnson'
order by orig_rn, part_length;

LAST_NAME            FIRST_NAME           PART                   
-------------------- -------------------- ------------------------
Johnson              Charles                                       
Johnson              Charles              C                        
Johnson              Charles              Ch                       
Johnson              Charles              Cha                      
Johnson              Charles              Char                     
Johnson              Charles              Charl                    
Johnson              Charles              Charle                   
Johnson              Charles              Charles
```

The next CTE, `u` (yes, sorry about the names, I was uninspired) compares the values across all the rows and counts the occurrences. Anything with a count of `1` is unique.

```
...
u as (
  select last_name, first_name, orig_rn, part, part_length,
    count(distinct orig_rn) over (partition by last_name) as last_name_count,
    count(distinct orig_rn) over (partition by last_name, part) as part_count
  from t
)
select last_name, first_name, part, last_name_count, part_count
from u
where last_name = 'Roberts'
order by orig_rn, part_length;

LAST_NAME            FIRST_NAME           PART                     LAST_NAME_COUNT PART_COUNT
-------------------- -------------------- ------------------------ --------------- ----------
Roberts              Chris                                                       2          2 
Roberts              Chris                C                                      2          2 
Roberts              Chris                Ch                                     2          2 
Roberts              Chris                Chr                                    2          2 
Roberts              Chris                Chri                                   2          2 
Roberts              Chris                Chris                                  2          2 
Roberts              Christian                                                   2          2 
Roberts              Christian            C                                      2          2 
Roberts              Christian            Ch                                     2          2 
Roberts              Christian            Chr                                    2          2 
Roberts              Christian            Chri                                   2          2 
Roberts              Christian            Chris                                  2          2 
Roberts              Christian            Christ                                 2          1 
Roberts              Christian            Christi                                2          1 
Roberts              Christian            Christia                               2          1 
Roberts              Christian            Christian                              2          1
```

The third CTE `v` only looks at the unique ones, and then ranks them according to the length of the unique value; so the shortest contraction of the first name for a record that is unique across all records is ranked as `1`.

```
...
v as (
  select last_name, first_name, orig_rn, part, last_name_count,
  row_number() over (partition by orig_rn order by part_length) as rn
  from u
  where (part_count = 1 or part = first_name)
)
select last_name, first_name, part, last_name_count
from v
where rn = 1
order by orig_rn;

LAST_NAME            FIRST_NAME           PART                     LAST_NAME_COUNT
-------------------- -------------------- ------------------------ ---------------
Johnson              Charles                                                     1 
Roberts              Chris                Chris                                  2 
Roberts              Christian            Christ                                 2 
Smith                Albert               Alb                                    3 
Smith                Alphonse             Alp                                    3 
Smith                Jason                J                                      3
```

Then the final query just extracts those ranked `1`, which are the shortest unique values, and formats them the way you wanted.

If two people have exactly the same name then both are spelled out in full ([demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/644c6/1)) which seems to be what you want from your comment.

Not sure if this really qualifies as 'cleaner', except that it only hits the original table once.

Comment: Very cool.  I will have to wrap my head around this for a bit.  It does seem to meed all the requirements so I will mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
with
last_names as (
  select last_name, count(*) as last_name_count 
  from table_name 
  group by last_name )

select case 
         when b.last_name_count = 1 then a.last_name 
         else substr(a.first_name,1,1)||'. '||a.last_name 
       end as name
from table_name a
join last_names b
on a.last_name = b.last_name;
```

replacing `table_name` with the right name.

Comment: That doesn't give unique values though; you have two `A.Smith` and two `C.Roberts`?

Comment: This works, but just for appending the first initial if needed.  It doesn't go any deeper.